# how to use sync api to upload file to dropbox android

Tags: android, dropbox

I am a new android developer, I want to write a program to upload a specify file from my mobile to Dropbox whenever it is updated in local.

Should I use Sync API or Core API? Or both can archieve my aim?

For using SYNC api, how can i locate the local file location?

Thanks.

Comment: do u want to locate to your app folder or any other folder?

Comment: I want to some personal folder.

Comment: DropboxAPI.Entry newEntry2 = mDBApi.putFileOverwrite("" + filename, inputStream, file.length(),null); it stores in ur app folder

Comment: Also, use this access type final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;

Comment: Hi, Thats mean i can only use CoreAPI, right?
Can Sync api do the same?

Comment: I am currently trying to implement this, i will answer you as soon as i finish uploading

Answer (score 0):

Answer of your Question ... upload file using dropbox sync api

[Upload file using Dropbox sync api u](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20100698/1837813)